# Given a log file with API names, start and end timestamps, write a program that prints the average latency for each API call

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Q: Given a log file with API names, start and end timestamps, write a program that prints the average latency for each API call.

It was asked in google interview, my solution got rejected. So, want to know how can this be solved in optimized way.

$ cat log

get_foo start 2222222100

get_foo end 2222222150

get_bar start 2222222200

get_foo start 2222222220

get_bar end 2222222230

get_foo end 2222222250

solution :
$ cat log | myprog

get_foo: average = 40
get_bar: average = 30

Comment: Nice task, what have you tried so far?

Comment: It was asked in google interview, my solution got rejected. So, want to know how can this be solved in optimized way.

Comment: How did your solution look? Can you please add it to your question?

Comment: In Java or only with linux shell?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Collection<Long>>` for the start times that have not yet been matched with end times. Whenever you meet an end time, remove any start time from the corresponding collection, subtract and register into your stats (wrong matchings don’t matter, they will balance out).

Comment: Can we see like
my_api start
my_api start
my_api stop
my_api stop
? there are two solutions for this?

Comment: @v78 Both solutions will give the same average.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to breakdown the process to simplify the complexity of your problem.

Here could be a good starting point about how to define the process :

[image: process activity]

Done in Java, it could lead to this :

```
public class Program {
    // The HashMap which contains api keys and object wrappers associated to it.
    private Map<String, ApiCall> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    /**
     * getHashMap
     * Setter of the hashMap which contains api keys and object wrappers
     * associated to it.
     * @return
     */
    public Map<String, ApiCall> getHashMap() {
        return hashMap;
    }
    /**
     * setHashMap
     * Getter of the hashMap which contains api keys and object wrappers
     * associated to it.
     * @param hashMap
     */
    public void setHashMap(Map<String, ApiCall> hashMap) {
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }
    /**
     * getNewApiCall
     * @return a new ApiCall wrapper object
     */
    public ApiCall getNewApiCall() {
        return new ApiCall();
    }
    /**
     * main
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Program app = new Program();
        // Arbitrary path to test with my environment
        String path = args.length > 1 ? args[0] : "/home/user/test";
        // Read all lines from your log file
        List<Object> lines = Arrays.asList(
            Files.lines(
                Paths.get(new File(path).getPath())
            ).toArray()
        );
        for (Object o:lines) {
            String s = o.toString().trim();
            // If it's not and empty line
            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                /*
                 * Split the lines into array with
                 * [0] = api_name, [1] start or end, [2] timestamp
                 */
                String[] values = s.split(" ");
                // Add the API call to a hashmap without any value
                app.getHashMap().put(values[0], null);
                // Here you have all name of calls of your API

                /*
                 * Now for each api call, wrap it into an object that will
                 * handle the average computation, the array of start
                 * timestamps and the array of end timestamps
                 */
                ApiCall apiCall = app.getHashMap().get(values[0]);
                // Create and object for wrapping starting and ending timestamps
                if (apiCall == null) {
                    apiCall = app.getNewApiCall();
                }
                /*
                 * If the line is a start then parse the last value to a long
                 * and add it to the object wrapper to further compute for the
                 * average
                 */
                if (values[1].equals("start")) {
                    apiCall.addStart(Long.parseLong(values[2]));
                }
                /*
                 * Else it is a end timestamp then parse the last value of the
                 * line to a long and add it to the object wrapper to further
                 * compute for the average
                 */
                else {
                    apiCall.addEnd(Long.parseLong(values[2]));
                }
                // Add the new incremented object wrapper to the API key
                app.getHashMap().put(values[0], apiCall);
            }
        }
        /*
         * Stream hashmap entries (API keys) and print the key and the average
         * value for each
         */
        app.getHashMap().entrySet().forEach(
            ks -> System.out.println(
                ks.getKey()+" average="+ks.getValue().getAverage()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The class leading to object to wrap starting and ending timestamps for a specific API call for further computation.

```
/**
 * ApiCall
 * Class allowing to collect starting timestamps and ending timestamp for
 * an API call. Compute the average on each addition.
 * @author user
 * @since 12 sept. 2019
 */
public class ApiCall {
    private List<Long> start;
    private List<Long> end;
    private double average;
    public ApiCall() {
        start = new ArrayList<>();
        end = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void addStart(Long l) {
        start.add(l);
        setAverage(computeAverage());
    }
    public void addEnd(Long l) {
        end.add(l);
        setAverage(computeAverage());
        }
    public double getAverage() {
        return this.average;
    }
    private void setAverage(Double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }
    private double computeAverage() {
        return
        (
            end.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).average().orElse(0.0)
            - start.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).average().orElse(0.0)
        );
    }
}
```

I just did this to give you a starting point about how to do. Don't copy/paste because the code is badly written and there is surely errors about the average computation as you can see in the output :

```
get_bar average=2.22222223E9
get_foo average=2.22222225E9
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did exactly the same but the google interviewer rejected and I do not know why